# Displaying an acinerella packet into my form

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I have a fire monkey form in RAD Studio xe6 and I am using acinerella as a wrapper for ffmpeg in order to play a video. In the only available example that is shipped together with acinerella we can see the line

```
175| Move(videodecoder^.buffer^, bmp.Scanline[bmp.Height-1]^, videodecoder^.buffer_size);
```

That can no longer be used though as ScanLine does not exist. What is the fastest method to display a packet in my form?

**EDIT**

I found a way that at least compiles, but doesn't show anything in the final form.

it includes using vcl.tbitmap so the scan line can work, saving that to a stream and loading it to my fmx.tbitmap. Something like

```
Move(videodecoder^.buffer^, bmp.Scanline[bmp.Height-1]^, videodecoder^.buffer_size);
bmp.SaveToStream(aStream);
aStream.Position := 0;
ImageViewer1.Bitmap.LoadFromStream(aStream);
```

Is this even going in the right direction.

Comment: You can use [Map](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/FMX.Graphics.TBitmap.Map) to access a bitmap's raw pixels. Is that what you're after?

Comment: Yes I did read about map and tried a few things but with no results. I tried using this article [http://members.adug.org.au/2012/10/05/read-write-image-bitmap-pixels-in-delphi-xe3/]. An example on my particular case would be helpful. I need to transfer the data from the buffer provided by acinerella to an ImageViewer as I see it.

Comment: What are "no results"? Map will let you copy pixels to a bitmap... which is what you want to do? Perhaps you can add that code to the question and explain what isn't working.

Comment: True, but I am not sure what is  inside the packet that acinerella gives me. As far as I've seen its just a big number that I have no idea how to pass into a pixel of a TImage.